# 'Relation does not exist' error when trying to run docker-compose in docker-machine cookiecutter-django

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have completed my Django Project using cookiecutter-django.
If I just locally run:

```
$ docker-compose -f local.yml build

$ docker-compose -f local.yml up
```

My project launches just fine in http://0.0.0.0:8000

Nonetheless, now I am trying to deploy it following this guide: https://realpython.com/development-and-deployment-of-cookiecutter-django-via-docker/

I have been able to create the local docker-machine with `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev`, activate it `eval $(docker-machine env dev)` and build the image, but if I run `docker-compose -f local.yml up` then I get the following error:

```
Attaching to innovacion_innsai_postgres_1, innovacion_innsai_django_1, innovacion_innsai_node_1
postgres_1  | 2020-03-12 09:14:42.686 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-03-12 09:14:42.686 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-03-12 09:14:42.688 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2020-03-12 09:14:42.702 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-11 10:05:23 UTC
postgres_1  | 2020-03-12 09:14:42.732 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
django_1    | PostgreSQL is available
django_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "innovation_sector" does not exist
django_1    | LINE 1: ...n_sector"."id", "innovation_sector"."sector" FROM "innovatio...
django_1    |                                                              ^
django_1    | 
django_1    | 
django_1    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django_1    | 
django_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1    |   File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
django_1    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
django_1    |     utility.execute()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
django_1    |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
django_1    |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
django_1    |     self.check()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
django_1    |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
django_1    |     issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
django_1    |     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
django_1    |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
django_1    |     return check_resolver(resolver)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
django_1    |     return check_method()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
django_1    |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
django_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
django_1    |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
django_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
django_1    |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1    |   File "/app/config/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
django_1    |     path("", include("innovacion_innsai.innovation.urls", namespace="innovation")),
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
django_1    |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1    |   File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
django_1    |     from innovacion_innsai.innovation import views
django_1    |   File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/views.py", line 9, in <module>
django_1    |     from .analytics import alimentacion_cases, agro_cases, turismo_cases, movilidad_cases
django_1    |   File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/analytics.py", line 17, in <module>
django_1    |     for case in Case.objects.filter(sector__sector=sectors[0]):
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 308, in __getitem__
django_1    |     qs._fetch_all()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
django_1    |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
django_1    |     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1133, in execute_sql
django_1    |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
django_1    |     return super().execute(sql, params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
django_1    |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
django_1    |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
django_1    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "innovation_sector" does not exist
django_1    | LINE 1: ...n_sector"."id", "innovation_sector"."sector" FROM "innovatio...
django_1    |                                                              ^
django_1    | 
innovacion_innsai_django_1 exited with code 1
node_1      | 
node_1      | > innovacion_innsai@1.1.0 dev /app
node_1      | > gulp
node_1      | 
node_1      | [09:14:48] Using gulpfile /app/gulpfile.js
node_1      | [09:14:48] Starting 'default'...
node_1      | [09:14:48] Starting 'styles'...
node_1      | [09:14:48] Starting 'scripts'...
node_1      | [09:14:48] Starting 'imgCompression'...
node_1      | [09:14:48] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
node_1      | [09:14:48] Finished 'imgCompression' after 34 ms
node_1      | [09:14:48] Finished 'scripts' after 128 ms
node_1      | [09:14:49] Finished 'styles' after 1.09 s
node_1      | [09:14:49] Starting 'initBrowserSync'...
node_1      | [09:14:49] Starting 'watchPaths'...
node_1      | [Browsersync] Proxying: http://django:8000
node_1      | [Browsersync] Access URLs:
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      |        Local: http://localhost:3000
node_1      |     External: http://172.20.0.4:3000
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      |           UI: http://localhost:3001
node_1      |  UI External: http://localhost:3001
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
```

In case it might be relevant, if I visit the docker-machine's IP adreess and port (http://192.168.99.101:2376) before launching docker-compose build o up, the page displays "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."

Here is my 'local.yml':

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: innovacion_innsai_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: innovacion_innsai_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/node/Dockerfile
    image: innovacion_innsai_local_node
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      # http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      # Expose browsersync UI: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ui
      - "3001:3001"
```

the result of running docker-machine ls:

```
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
dev    -        virtualbox     Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v19.03.5
```

My .postgresql in the .envs/.local folder is:

```
# PostgreSQL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=innovacion_innsai
POSTGRES_USER=debug
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=debug
```

and my Docker file for local:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apt-get install -y gettext \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

Please, I am quite new with Django and Docker so excuse me if I did not explain myself properly. Also, please let me know if you would need any other script or information in order to take a proper look at the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you already figured this out and I don't know if I'm right but give this a try:

Instead of:

```sh
docker-compose -f local.yml up
```

Try:

```sh
docker-compose -f production.yml up
```

When you're deploying to production you should build and bring up the site with the production file not the local file.